# Elliptic and Fredholm partial differential operators

Tags: partial-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, differential-operators, elliptic-equations

As I learn from the comments to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182415/elliptic-operators-corresponds-to-non-vanishing-vector-fields) a non elliptic operator on a compact manifold can not be a fredholm operator.

**However, I learn also from the  conversations  in the  same  post that  the  hypoelliptic  operators  can be    Fredholm  but  non  elliptic operators**

On the other hand it seems that the following operator is fredholm(At least, algebraically):

For  a Morse function $F:S^{2}\to \mathbb{R}$ which has only two singular points(one max at N  and one min at S), define $D:C^{\infty}(S^{2})\to C^{\infty}(S^{2})$ with $D(g)= \nabla F. \nabla g$.

The simple dynamical structure of the gradient vector field $\nabla F$  easily shows that the kernel of $D$ is one dimensional and codimension of the range is 2. So  apparently we have  a fredholm operator.

> Is not this a contradictory situation?

It is written in the comments to the above question that this is a fredholm opeartor, algebrically but not analytically. Can one help me to understand this statement?

Comment: I can see that the kernel of $D$ contains only constant functions, but how do you argue that the codimension of the range is 2?

Comment: @LukasGeyer  Assume  that $h$ is  an  smooth  function on the spher  with $h(P)=h(N)=0$. We  deined   $D(g)=X.g$ the derivation of  $g$  along the  trajectories of  $X$  where  $X$  has  jyst  two  singularity  at  $N$  and  $P$. We denote  by  $\phi_{t}$ the  flow  of the  vector  field  $X$. Them $g(x)= \int_{-\infty } ^{+\infty} h(\phi_{t}(x))dt$  satisfies $X.g=h$. this  obviousely  shows that  the  codimension of  the  range  of $D$  is  two. Note  that the  integral is  convergent  since  we  assumed that the  singularities  are  hyperbolic, so  they  attract  the orbits  exponentially.

Comment: @LukasGeyer  The  singularities  are  hyperbolic since  we choos  $X$ as a  gradient  vector  field  associated  with  a  morse  function with  a  Maximum  and  a  minimum.

Comment: Just to elaborate, if you assume that the max and min are 1 and 0, then it seems you will only get maps in your image whose integral along the gradient flow lines of $F$ are 1. However, a generic smooth function will not have the same integral along each of the flow lines, indicating that the codimension of the range is infinite.

Comment: Ali, your function $g$ will in general not have a continuous extension to $P$ and $N$, unless I am missing something.

Comment: @LukasGeyer  Thank  you  very  much  for  your  answer. I was  mistaken.I  did  the  same  mistake  as in the  incorrect  proposition of the  following  note: The  proposition says  the  codimension of the range  IS EQUALE  to the  number  of  limit  cycles but the  true  version is  that  the codimension of the range  is  an upper  bound  for  the  number  of  limit  cycles:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0408037.pdf

Comment: The  true  version is  indicated  in the second  part  of the  following  note:https://arxiv.org/abs/1302.0001

Comment: The  situation is  also  discussed  in  a  talk by  Loic  Teyssier  https://cms.math.ca/Events/Toulouse2004/abs/ss7.html#lt

Comment: @LukasGeyer  For  a related  post  please see the  following:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/164059/codimension-of-the-range-of-certain-linear-operators

Comment: @LukasGeyer What  function  algebra  is appropriate for  action of  the  operator  $D$? That  is what  algebra  $A$ of  functions  is invariant  under $D$ with the property  that  $A$  seperates compact subsets of the  plane  and  the  codimension  of  $D$  is  finite?

Comment: Ali: Sorry, I have no idea what the appropriate function algebra would be.